# WordPress Horizontal Sub-Nav

Tags: html, css, wordpress, submenu

Trying to get a wordpress subnav to display below my main nav in a single horizontal row. Traditionally I can do this by displaying my li elements inline in a ul that is set to a specific size and position. However, working in WordPress is a bit more limiting.

What happens is that the ul ul items appear directly below the menu item instead of occupying the width of the header.

HELP!

Here's the code for the whole navigation:

```
<div class="navWrap">
<header class="navigation">
        <a href="<?php echo home_url('/')?>"><div id="logo"></div></a><!-- site-logo -->
        <!-- social-media start -->
        <a href="http://pinterest.com" target="_blank"><div id="pin"></div></a>
        <a href="http://instagram.com" target="_blank"><div id="ig"></div></a>
        <a href="http://facebook.com" target="_blank"><div id="fb"></div></a>
        <!-- social-media end -->
        <nav>
        <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary' ) ); ?>
    </nav><!-- #site-navigation -->
</header><!-- #masthead -->
</div>
```

Here are the CSS modifiers:

```
.navWrap {
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    min-height:100px;
    position:fixed;
    top:20px;
}

.navigation {
    width:940px;
    padding:20px 20px 10px 20px;
    margin:0px auto 20px auto;
    background-color:#9AD2AE;
    background-image:url(images/bg_header_001.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:right center;
    overflow:auto;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px -4px rgba(46,46,46,1);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px -4px rgba(46,46,46,1);
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px -4px rgba(46,46,46,1);
}
```

And the sub-menu CSS:

```
ul ul { 
display: none; 
position: fixed;
z-index:9999;
min-width:100px;
padding:30px 0px 10px 0px;
}
ul ul li { 
background-color:#9ec3ab;
height: 22px;
z-index:9999;
text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: Link to the problematic page?

Comment: Give us either a link or the output HTML for the menu. The PHP version doesn't give use enough information. We need to know the actual ul li ul li output (with classes and all)